# Derive a record datatype without template haskell

Tags: generics, haskell, type-families, deriving, ghc-generics

So, I've been toying around a little bit with GHC.Generics, which are great, but seem limited/focused mainly on generating instances.

What I would like to do, if possible, is to derive a new data type from another.

Let's say you've got the following type:

```
data Xpto = Xpto {
    fstt :: First Int
    lstt :: Last String }
```

I would like to obtain the following data type 'for free':

```
data Xpto' = Xpto' {
   fstt' :: Int
   lstt' :: String }
```

One possibility I've considered was to use type families, but then the new data would have to get the same kind as Xpto:

```
class Xptos newtyped where
   type UnNewTyped un :: (same kind as newtyped)
```

I'm starting to think none of this is possible, and I'm sure there are good reasons for that.

Note 1: I know this is probably feasible with Template Haskell... just wondering if there is any other way.

Comment: Why do you need this new data type?

Comment: Let's say you've got a complicated record. Then, you want to combine various of those records as a monoid, but some of the maybe fields you want to behave like First, others like Last. Right now you have to declare two data types, a conversion among them, and then use generics.deriving.monoid to derive the monoid instance for the 'newtyped' version. I'm aiming to reduce the boiler plate of 'duplicate but related' record datatypes.

Comment: Maybe you could approach this problem differently, by making working with the original data type more comfortable, without needing a new, easier data type?

Comment: This isn't possible, GHC.Generics won't let you make brand new declarations. For that you'd need template Haskell. In this case though, making a newtype wrapper around the record and making monoid instances of that is the right approach it seems

Comment: As I feared. If you turn your comment to an answer I'll mark it as the correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if you can change all your types at this point, but what about something like `data Xpto_ f g = Xpto_ {fstt :: f Int, lstt :: g String }; type Xpto = Xpto_ First Last; type Xpto' = Xpto_ Identity Identity` This is basically as "free" as you can get the second type.